# Apply onchange to specific form fields and set a new hidden input

Tags: javascript, onchange

I am building an events form, there is an option to add recurring event rules.

I have the form working with related expand to show the recurring event rules. This expand div already has allot of JS to deal with disabling / enabling fields that are not required based on rule types... notably all the recurring form fields are defined in a json object.

I want to be able to detect if the rules have changed during a form save - if the recurring rules have changed I need to do allot of server side processing, so I only want to do this if the rules have changed.

I am thinking about using JS to dynamically apply an onchange call to each field in the recurring form module.

I am pretty new to JS, so before I go further, are there any opinions on how best to do this? Pure Javascript only please!

The final part is to then add a post var to the form, which I can detect in my submit script and then run the required recurring event rules.. This is not a "fix this bit of code" question, more of a best approach question.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to check it server side during the self? that way if you see any recurring stuff changed you can run your rules.

Comment: I think its going to be simpler in the long run to do this client side, but yes, I suppose I could compare the current values to the new values in POST...

Comment: Determining if you need to do a lot of server-side processing would be better to do on the server side as if you make that decision and do the processing based on a a field change, you're going to be doing a lot of unnecessary processing due to people changing fields, making typos, etc. Plus it open the door to a DOS situation if changing a field on a form can trigger that much server side processing.

Comment: yes, upon consideration, server side will be better here. Thanks for the advice guys..